# What is wrong with my prime function

Tags: vb.net

I'm a beginner in vb and I'm wondering why this code doesn't work.
I wrote the function which I can't seem to find why it doesn't. When I run the program, it seems to print out nothing.

I am supposed to find all the prime numbers between 1 and the input

```
Option Strict On
Public Class Lab4
   Dim endCounter As Integer
   Dim sum As Integer
   Dim msg As String
   Dim input As Integer

Public Function isPrime(input As Integer) As Boolean
    endCounter = input - 1

    For primeCounter As Integer = 1 To endCounter
        If input Mod primeCounter <> 0 Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    Next
    Return False
End Function

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnPrime_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrime.Click
    input = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumber.Text)
    msg = "The prime numbers are: "

    If input < 0 Then
        msg = "Number cannot be negative!"

        For inputCounter As Integer = 1 To input
            If isPrime(inputCounter) = True Then
                msg += inputCounter & " "
            End If
        Next
        MsgBox(msg, , "Prime Number")
End Sub
    End If
```

End Class

Comment: And you cannot find out what part runs in an infinite loop, because..? Adding simple print statements inside suspects would be enough. Are you testing this with fairly small numbers (10, 100, 1000) or are you going wild and testing with 63524266452 or something in that vein?

Comment: I made a mistake, I didn't mean infinite loop, I meant that it doesn't print out the prime numbers. I've been using 10 and 100 but nothing prints out

Comment: Use your debugger!  Put a breakpoint in the first line of your `btnProme_Click` event and step through the code line by line.  You will learn a lot!  Also, you have a syntax error.  You have `End If` *after* the `End Sub`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This test will *always* immediately return something on the very first test:

```
Public Function isPrime(input As Integer) As Boolean
    endCounter = input - 1

    For primeCounter As Integer = 1 To endCounter
        If input Mod primeCounter <> 0 Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    Next
    Return False
End Function
```

because you use `Return` immediately after the 'has modulus' line. Remove the `Return True` and `else` lines, so it only returns `False` if a modulus value is found. The very last line should be `Return True` – *no* modulus values are found, so it is a prime.

For this to work, you need to change your test to

```
If input Mod primeCounter == 0 Then
```

*and* change the start test from `1` to `2`.

You don't need to test against `1`, and you don't need to test all the way up to `input` or (you probably misunderstood something there) `input - 1`. The most logical endpoint is `ceil(sqrt(input))`, the next higher number of the square root of your starting value.

Comment: Do this. I obviously did not look at the results from the function.

Comment: I figured out the problem. The If statement was stopping the msg from printing